# Change dataframe value in parallel

Tags: r, data-preprocessing

I spent some time changing data in R for preprocessing purposes. I go through some 800,000 lines of data so running this in parallel would be faster. I thought this might be beneficial to other people if you want to change data in your dataframe without writing data to another frame first. I posted some code of what I was doing before and what I am doing now. IT is much faster. Both get the same answer. How would I run this in parallel.

What I didn't know about foreach and doParallel is the difference between using %dopar% and %do%. %do% will change data in the dataframe and %dopar% will not; however, dopar runs in parallel. I'm not sure if %do% runs parallel or not.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(doParallel)

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1, outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)

data = data.frame(ID=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"),
                  original_ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                  ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                  Proccessed = "",
                  pattern1 = "")


female.inbred = "([\\(]{0,6}[?:-[[:alnum:]]+]{0,20}[\\)]{0,6})"
male.inbred = "([\\(]{0,6}[?:-[[:alnum:]]+]{0,20}[\\)]{0,6})"
generation = "(?:-[[:alnum:]]+){3}"

conv1 = paste0("^",female.inbred, "/", male.inbred, generation)

#############one core version#########################3
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern = "\\.DH")){
    if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
      if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
        if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(GA21")){
          if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\:")){
            if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern ="\\.")){
              
              
              if(lengths(regmatches(data[i,3], gregexpr("/", data[i,3]))) == 1){
                
                if(str_detect(data[i,3], pattern = conv1)){
                  data[i,4] = "Proccessed" # add a period for using wildcards
                  
                  replacement = str_match(pattern = conv1, data[i,3])
                  data[i,5] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                  data[i,3] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                  
                }}} }}}}}}

data
> data
  ID                original_ped                 ped Proccessed            pattern1
1 a1        fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6      fff/abc)-1-2-3 Proccessed      fff/abc)-1-2-3
2 a2 addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B   addf/asdf)-3-05-4 Proccessed   addf/asdf)-3-05-4
3 a3   (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3 (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5 Proccessed (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5
4 a4             addf/eed).DH1-B     addf/eed).DH1-B                               






################DoParrallelVersion###################
#for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
data = data.frame(ID=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"),
                  original_ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                  ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                  Proccessed = "",
                  pattern1 = "")


bind.data=foreach(i=(1:nrow(data)),
                      .packages=c("tidyverse"),
                      .export=c("str_detect"),
                    .combine=rbind,
                    .multicombine=T
                  
) %do% {
  if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern = "\\.DH")){
    if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
      if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
        if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(GA21")){
          if(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\:")){
            if(!str_detect(data[i,3], pattern ="\\.")){
              
              
              if(lengths(regmatches(data[i,3], gregexpr("/", data[i,3]))) == 1){
                
                if(str_detect(data[i,3], pattern = conv1)){
                  data[i,4] = "Proccessed" # add a period for using wildcards
                  
                  replacement = str_match(pattern = conv1, data[i,3])
                  data[i,5] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                  data[i,3] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                  
                }}} }}}}}}
#bind.data
data

> data
  ID                original_ped                 ped Proccessed            pattern1
1 a1        fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6      fff/abc)-1-2-3 Proccessed      fff/abc)-1-2-3
2 a2 addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B   addf/asdf)-3-05-4 Proccessed   addf/asdf)-3-05-4
3 a3   (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3 (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5 Proccessed (ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5
4 a4             addf/eed).DH1-B     addf/eed).DH1-B
```

Comment: Are you asking a question here? Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, it's not meant to be used as a blogging site. Perhaps you can re-write your post to be more of a question and then you can self-answer your question below. Then others can post alternative solutions and the community can upvote which they like the best. You've chosen a very odd sample dataset. Perhaps choose something that makes it easier to see exactly what problem you are trying to solve if you just want to share an answer..

Comment: I'm trying to run this in parallel. I don't know if the %do% statement runs in parallel like the %dopar% statement does.

Comment: From the `?foreach::foreach` help page: "`%do%` evaluates the expression sequentially, while `%dopar%` evaluates it in parallel."

Comment: when I use %dopar% it dosen't return my dataframe of adjusted values. Is there a way to use %dopar% and return the dataframe of my adjusted values?

Comment: When running in parallel, you cannot modify some global object - you'll run into problems when reach thread tries to update the global state at the same time. You need to change your code to a strategy that actually works in parallel. Not all procedures can run in parallel.

Comment: I run it line-by-line so is there i way i could run each row seperatly then rbind them back together in a new dataframe in parallel and order does not matter?

Comment: (Is there a reason you have `(!grepl(data[i,3], pattern ="\\(wx"))` as two separate `if` statements? Is there a reason you use both `grepl` and `str_detect`? They both do the same thing, I find it interesting that you don't use one of the two for all of your checks.)

Comment: I have data that contains wx in the original, this is a trait in the line I'm changing and I would like to skip these rows. I left it in so these conditions in so it wouldn't change my answer if i were to add more of these in. as For grepl and str_detect, for some reason str_detect is cleaner then grepl for some of the strings i use. I think it has to do with the regex I use. grepl wont always return a false statment whereas str_detect will.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found a nice reference to https://hernanresnizky.com/2014/01/10/quick-guide-to-parallel-r-with-snow/
However, I added a function to be evaluated and returned the dataframe so when i evaluate this in parallel i use the "i" variable in the function where the dataframe is used. This is a bypass around changing a global object in parallel. It allows rows to be appended after it is adjusted via the function.

```
   cov1 = function(data){
    #for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      if(!str_detect(data[,3], pattern = "\\.DH")){
        if(!grepl(data[,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
          if(!grepl(data[,3], pattern ="\\(wx")){
            if(!str_detect(data[,3], pattern ="\\(GA21")){
              if(!grepl(data[,3], pattern ="\\:")){
                if(!str_detect(data[,3], pattern ="\\.")){
                  
                  
                  if(lengths(regmatches(data[,3], gregexpr("/", data[,3]))) == 1){
                    
                    if(str_detect(data[,3], pattern = conv1)){
                      data[,4] = "Proccessed" # add a period for using wildcards
                      
                      replacement = str_match(pattern = conv1, data[,3])
                      data[,5] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                      data[,3] = replacement[1] # add a period for using wildcards
                      
                    }}} }}}}}
      return(data.frame(data))
    }
    
    
    
    
    ################DoParrallelVersion###################
    #for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    data = data.frame(ID=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"),
                      original_ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                      ped = c("fff/abc)-1-2-3-4-5-6","addf/asdf)-3-05-4-3-1-3-4-B","(ekkdi/kdici)-3-4-5-B-3-3","addf/eed).DH1-B"),
                      Proccessed = "",
                      pattern1 = "")
    
    bind.data=foreach(i=(1:nrow(data)),
                      .packages=c("tidyverse"),
                      .export=c("str_detect"),
                      .combine=rbind,
                      .inorder=F
                      #.multicombine=T,
    
    ) %dopar% {
      a=cov1(data=data[i,])
      a
    }
    bind.data
```